# Disallowing link from opening in Forward email

Tags: authentication, email-forwarding

we have a use-case wherein a notification email is sent out in response to some postings on forum. This notification emails carry a AHREF link which basically allows to launch the post page from the email itself. Additionally, these links carry an authentication token so that the user don't have to sign in when opening the page. This works fine in the normal use case, but in the scenario when the original recipient forwards the email to some other account we are not sure how we identify that the link is opened from forwarded email address. Can somebody provide some insight ?

Comment: That's true. My apologies, I will correct it is  AHREF and not MAILTO:

Answer (score 1):

There is principally no way for you to detect that a link was clicked in an email that was forwarded vs. an email that you sent directly to someone.

Do not put an authentication bypass in the link if the need to secure your content outweighs the need for user friendliness.

You can weigh allowing the user, once they log in, to set a persistent authentication cookie in the browser they logged in from.  That way, if they click a link in an email and that cookie is set, they can get directly into the website.  StackOverflow.com works that way, which is convenient and the downside risk is not too great. Fortunately my bank does not work that way.  The potential for loss is much greater with home banking.

Comment: How about this approach am not sure of the technical feasibility ? Insert a javascript in the AHREF to get current user's email address and it that doesn't match the expected email address don't allo ?

Comment: JavaScript has no way to access the current user's email address.  JavaScript runs in a security sandbox within the browser.  Trust me, what you want cannot be done.  You *can* do something like what StackOverflow does.  If you were logged into StackOverflow any time in the past and you click a link to here (say from a google search, or a link you email yourself), you will be automatically logged in.  If you open a link in a browser where you weren't logged in, you are first prompted to log in.  That will solve your problem.